# An oracle relative to which EXP(NP) = BPP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, oracles, relativization

Whether or not $\mathbf{BPP} = \mathbf{EXP}^{\mathbf{NP}}$ is an open problem, although we believe the former is strictly contained in the other.  I guess, from the absence of the proof of the separation, that there should have been  a relativized result on this problem, namely, the existence of an oracle relative to which $\mathbf{BPP} = \mathbf{EXP}^{\mathbf{NP}}$.

Is there such a result in the literature indeed?

Comment: Yes, there are oracles making them equal and oracles making them different, if I recall. Lance Fortnow knows the reference... I can try to look it up myself, but if you do a search on sciencedirect for it, you're likely to see it.

Comment: Lance Fortnow does know the reference :) http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/08/extreme-oracles.html

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino The link on Fortnow's blog is dead.  I would accept your answer if you could provide me with more concrete bibliographic information.

Comment: Heller is the first http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(86)80012-2

Comment: I went back to the blog entry and replaced the links with DOIs that should last forever.

Comment: @Alessandro care to post as an answer?